# end-of-month or not for plain vanilla interest rate swap

Tags: interest-rate-swap

Quick and hopefully simple question about a standard swap schedule. Let's say we have a plain vanilla 3y fix-flt interest rate swap with cpn-freq = 1, no stubs, in for example EUR.
Start date: 2021-11-29 (NOT last bus day in month)
Maturity:   2024-11-29 (last bus day in month)
If I just have a quote on a screen what should be assumed regarding the intermediary roll dates? Should they be on the end-of-moth dates or not i.e.
[2022-11-29, 2023-11-29] or [2022-11-30, 2023-11-30]?
Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to answer without looking at the contract. The only thing I can tell you is that 90% of the swaps that I have seen with broken period, had the broken period at the beginning of the swap, so the payment schedule was built starting from the maturity.

Comment: Can't be certain from the given information, but usualy if people want the date to roll on 11/30, they'd give 11/30 as the start date; if it's not a business day in 2021, it would be bumped to 11/29 under modified following rule. As Sebastian said, usually, but not always, the dates march backwards from the maturity date, with the odd period remaining at the beginning.

Comment: I guess my question is what is the implied market convention for a standard let's say fix vs Euribor float as it is displayed on a market screen (eg. icap reuter page). Obviously I don't have a contract but the rate on the market screen obviously implies some rules. The "screen swaps" all have straight periods ... no stub periods. The start date is 2021-11-29 which is t+2. You can roll fwd or roll backward ... both implies no stub period either in front or in the end in this case. The question is if the eom-rule is triggered from the maturity date or from the settlement date.

Comment: What is the settlement date?   21-11-29 or 21-11-25?

Comment: 21-11-29 = settlement date (= start date) ... and trade date = 21-11-25

Comment: Ok, then back to your original question, the intermediary dates are [2022-11-29, 2023-11-29]

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. In other words, in your opinion, the eom-rule is NOT triggered meaning that it is the settlement date that determines whether or not we roll with eom. I was actually guessing that in this case the eom-rule was triggered by maturity being last business day in month.

Comment: No, I just don't think there is eom-rule for vanilla swaps. I asked the question about the settlement date because I wanted to be sure the initial date of the first accrual period was 2021-11-29.

Comment: Without going to much into detail, the reason why I am saying there is no eom-rule for vanilla swaps is because these swaps are used to build the zero curves. I am not a trader but I have built these curves before and match them against Murex. Our swap builder had a vanilla swap pricer on it and we never used eom convenction for the bootstrapping. I was able to replicate the discount factors and price the swaps to 10^-15 accuracy. It there was eom-rule some swaps or some curves would have been off and they weren't.

Comment: My question actually also arises from issues with bootstrapping ... in my case the issue was getting error when comparing dates in two different algorithms. When you say you don't use eom convention at all I suppose you do use eom for the underlying ibor rates on the floating leg because there I'm pretty sure that most follow the eom convention (but there the trigger is the settlement date for the rate). I suppose it is not necessary for the swap payment dates to follow the eom-rule even if the underlying index rates use the eom-rule.

Comment: This is the code. The constructor: Schedule(Date effectiveDate,
                 const Date& terminationDate,
                 const Period& tenor,
                 const Calendar& calendar,
                 BusinessDayConvention convention,
                 BusinessDayConvention terminationDateConvention,
                 DateGeneration::Rule rule,
                 bool endOfMonth);

Comment: fixedSchedule in the swap pricer: Schedule fixedScheduleIni(swap_.settlement(), swap_.maturity(), swap_.freqPaymentFixed(), calendar, swap_.bdcFixed(), swap_.bdcFixed(), DateGeneration::Backward, false);

Comment: floating: Schedule floatingScheduleIni(swap_.settlement(), swap_.maturity(), swap_.freqPaymentFloating(), calendar, swap_.bdcFloating(), swap_.bdcFloating(), DateGeneration::Backward, false);

Comment: As you see eom-rule is false in both legs.

Comment: if you have just one single day wrong in the calendar of a currency you will find differences in some swaps and we didn't find any differences. We also checked schedules for a sample of swaps and everything matched.

Comment: if the swap start on 2021-11-29 and matures on 2024-11-29, the intermediary dates should be [2022-11-29, 2023-11-29]. The only reason why you could find these dates: [2022-11-30, 2023-11-30] is that these ones ([2022-11-29, 2023-11-29]) are not business days. But this is nothing to do with the eom-rule. This is just the modified following convention.

Comment: The error I stumbled into was that one of the algorithms was using the eom rule and rolling backwards and hence the I got [2022-11-30, 2023-11-30]. The other algorithm was also using eom-roll but was rolling forward and in that case the result was [2022-11-29, 2023-11-29]. Calendars were the same in both cases. Anyway, if the eom-flag is false then the result is non-ambiguous. Thanks for spending some time with this.

Comment: Good that you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a tricky question. In the 2021 ISDA the end-of-month convention was specified to mean last calendar date of the month instead of last business day (see https://www.isda.org/a/BNEgE/Key-Changes-in-the-2021-ISDA-Interest-Rate-Derivatives-Definitions-June-2021.pdf). As Sebastian correctly pointed out, swaps are usually rolled out from maturity. So I would say that, if you contractually agree that the eom-rule applies to the swap in scope, then it gets activated if the maturity date is the last calendar date of the month. But I couldn't find any document verifying this statement.

Having that said I always hear from my traders that the eom-rule does not apply to standard swaps. Assume you would have traded a 10y EURIOBOR swap on 2024-02-26, starting on 2024-02-28 and maturing on 2034-02-28. Assume further that the eom-rule applies to that swap and gets activated as maturity date is the last calendar date of the respective month. Then one would roll over 2024-02-29 (leap year) and this would imply a natural stub of 1d - which is definitely not standard.